# Error encountered configuring beaver to use http as the transport

Tags: logging

I am trying to use [beaver](https://github.com/josegonzalez/beaver) to send logs to a REST service, but am running into an error.

My config ( beaver.conf ) looks like the following:

```
[beaver] 
logstash_version: 1 
http_url: http://somedomain
```

I run beaver like so:

```
beaver -F json -c beaver.conf -f in.log -t http
```

I get the following error:

> [2014-06-19 13:45:49,505] INFO    Starting worker... [2014-06-19
>   13:45:49,506] INFO    Working... [2014-06-19 13:45:49,508] INFO
>   [801g480ea] - watching logfile /home/rex/workspace/in.log [2014-06-19
>   13:45:49,508] INFO    Starting queue consumer Process Process-1:1:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in
>   _bootstrap
>       self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Beaver-31-py2.7.egg/beaver/run_queue.py",
>   line 24, in run_queue
>       transport = create_transport(beaver_config, logger=logger)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Beaver-31-py2.7.egg/beaver/transports/**init**.py",
>   line 18, in create_transport
>       _module = **import**(module_path, globals(), locals(), class_name, -1)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Beaver-31-py2.7.egg/beaver/transports/http_transport.py",
>   line 4, in 
>       import requests ImportError: No module named requests

Why am I getting this error and what is the fix?

It *might* have something to do with using http as a transport since using the default (stdout) works, but I can't figure out why. i.e. the following command correctly sends logs to stdout.

```
beaver -c beaver.conf -f in.log
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, I needed to reinstall the python request package.

```
sudo pip install requests
```